# JSONArray response with Volley for Android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am posting some data into the database using Volley and I get the following jsonarray response.

```
[
  {
  "nickname":"panikos",
  "username":"panikos@gmail.com",
  "user_type":"LEADER",
  "latest_steps":"0"
  }
]
```

This is a sample of my code that unfortunately doesn't log out or debug the variable of "nickname" object:(.

```
final JsonArrayRequest jsonObjReq1 = new 
JsonArrayRequest(AppConfig.URL_GET_TEAM, jsonObject,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("TAG", response.toString());

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jresponse = 
                jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String nickname =                                 
           jresponse.getString("nickname");
                            Log.d("nickname",nickname);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //pDialog.dismiss();

                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }


    };
```

Any ideas? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: the code seems okay. are you adding `jsonObjReq1` to request queue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I the problem might be -  you are already getting `response` as  a `JSONArray`.

So, you can Call

`JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(0);`

and if you have more than 1 object in response, then

```
for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(i);
    String nickname = jresponse.getString("nickname");
    Log.d("nickname", nickname);
}
```

Remove this :

```
               try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jresponse = 
            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String nickname =                                 
       jresponse.getString("nickname");
                        Log.d("nickname",nickname);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

and add :

```
try {
    JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(0);
    String nickname = jresponse.getString("nickname");
    Log.d("nickname",nickname);
}catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The Code looks good, however i think you might be missing a call to add `jsonObjReq1` in the request queue. I would suggest to use [Singleton Pattern](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes jsonObjReq1 is in the queue.

Comment: AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq1, tag_json_obj);

Comment: But I don't whats wrong and can't read the nickname object. It's so annoying!

Comment: nope. I don't get any errors. I just put a breakpoint inside the onErrorResponse method and so nothing.

Comment: The breakpoint in JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response); gives the JSON Array response. So it gets there. After that things are getting messy.

Comment: I think if the app is not crashing, but must be leaving a volley log. can you show the log

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class org.json.JSONArray

Comment: at app.victory.walking.thewalkingviktory.InvitationBoard$4.onResponse(InvitationBoard.java:189)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!!!

```
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("TAG", response.toString());

                    try {

                        Log.d("JsonArray",response.toString());
                        for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            String nickname = jresponse.getString("nickname");
                            Log.d("nickname",nickname);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //pDialog.dismiss();

                }
```

There was no need to create a new JSONArray. It was created inside the onResponse() method. The next project I am assigned to do is going to have more complicate webservices.omg!!!

Comment: You don't have to and your own question .. Please accept my and if it was helpful

Comment: Hey, I am getting `can not resolve getJSONObject(int)`. Any guesses?