# How to show the Network Response body in android using volley

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley, multipart

How to show the Network response in android using volley

getting response in postman like this

[image]

how to show this response in android?

I tried this way using `JSONobject` but nothing happens

```
    VolleyMultipartRequest volleyMultipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                    Log.e("server", "status code: " + response.statusCode);
                    String resultResponse = new String(response.data);
                    try {

                        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(resultResponse);
                        String name = result.getString("name");
                        Log.e("sever", name + " " );
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("server", "error listener: " + error.getMessage());
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }) {


        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("name", "IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
            Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("file", new DataPart("img_file", AppHelper.getFileDataFromDrawable(getBaseContext(), bitmap), "image/jpeg"));
            return params;
        }
    };
```

I'm getting response object of `NetworkResponse` help me out to show the response body

Comment: What you are looking for is right over here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404133/jsonarray-response-with-volley-for-android][1]

Comment: I edited my question please check it

Comment: Im getting a response of NetworkResponse and the response.data is in a byte[] then how to show the body of response

Comment: @SolankiZeel can you post the string value of the `JSONObject result`?

Comment: i cant log or toast in try block so i cant get output of result

Comment: @SolankiZeel Try block wont affect logs or toast. You can also try debugging. Anyway, the fields name, type, tmp_name..etc might be wrapped inside another JsonObject so try using `JSONObject jsonresponse = result.getJSONObject("jsonObjectKey");` to get that before trying to get name and other details.

Comment: Can you please share "proper" response you getting from postman?also you get response.toString() method to read response in a console.

Comment: @sagarpotdar can you guide me how to use Multipart in volley to upload image to server

Comment: @SolankiZeel:-Please look at this :-https://gist.github.com/anggadarkprince/a7c536da091f4b26bb4abf2f92926594

Comment: I tried this but not uploading file @sagarpotdar

how can I upload file without converting bitmap to byte[]

Comment: @SolankiZeel:-What error you got?

Comment: Im getting null JSONarray response from server and it is not uploading my file to server

Comment: Can you share your url here.so we will try.

Comment: https://ganak.webadmin.rocks/api/v2/testfile.php @sagarpotdar

Comment: Did you tried ? @sagarpotdar

Comment: @sagarpotdar if you know how to do please help me https://ganak.webadmin.rocks/api/v2/testfile.php this is the link

Comment: @SolankiZeel:-Did you upload it on temp directory?Can you please share your postman window(only screenshot)?