# Android studio Volley - unable to access API

Tags: android, android-volley

Beginner alert.

I am trying to use Volley in Android Studio to access an API I've written and hosted on a paid web domain. I've pasted the code I'm using below.

The code is supposed to pass the API two parameters. The first parameter is named "apicall" and the second (a query to query from a mysql database) is named "q". However the on error response message is always returned (the log shows "pppp3: out").

I am able to access this API from a web page using Javascript. So I was just wondering if there is anything I'm missing in the code below?

```
        String num1 = "selectjson";
        String num2 = "Select Region_Name from regions";

        String url = String.format("https://xxxxxxxxx.co.za/api/query_database_api.php?apicall=%1$s&q=%2$s", num1, num2);

        Log.d(TAG, "pppp1: " + url);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        //atvAnimalName.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, "pppp2: " + "In");
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "pppp3: " + "out");
                    }
                });

// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        ClsMySingleton.getInstance(actAddSighting.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you won to debug volley using log change your onErrorResponse to

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
}
```

after that you can tell me the error,i will try to check the error

Edit: 
because your error log is :

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"Region_Name":"Southern Africa"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

this mean your server response is array,you can change your request to this:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                //atvAnimalName.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "pppp2: " + response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

hope this help

Comment: Thank you, I should have picked that up. The error is the following: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"Region_Name":"Southern Africa"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I can see now that I need to use a JSON array request

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404133/jsonarray-response-with-volley-for-android